Plotting 3x3 rotational matrices and improper rotations
I'm trying to find a good visualization for my students to help them understand 3x3-rotation matrices and improper rotations. They are tasked to solve the following two exercises (there's a bit more about the task itself but I'm just trying highlighting the significant parts):

Let f be a linear map with
$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, x \mapsto Ax$
and A is orthogonal matrix given by
$$A = \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&-2\\\ 2 & 2 & 1\\\2&-1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

Show that there exists a orthonormal basis (in regard to the standard scalar product) $B = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$, such that the transformation matrix of f in regard to B is given by:
$$M(f; B) = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\\0 & \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\\0 & \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Important task:
Show by sketch that f is a rotation around a onedimensional axis.

Now let g be the linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is a orthogonal reflection at the linear subspace $$U = \mathbb{R} \begin{pmatrix}0\\\0\\\1\end{pmatrix} + \mathbb{R} \begin{pmatrix}2\\\ -1\\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
Intepret the map $g \circ f$ graphically.

The first task is simple enough. You get that $\text{Eig}(f;1) = \mathbb{R}\begin{pmatrix}1\\\2\\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Now look at the restriction of f on the orthogonal complement of the eigenspace, which is a linear orthogonal transformation on a two dimensional vectorspace, so there exists some orthonormal basis $(v_2, v_3)$ of $\text{Eig}(f;1)^\perp$ such that the restriction is given by a rotation matrix. Then normalizing an eigenvector to the eigenvalue 1 of f gives the desired orthonormal basis.
So far so good. You can now interpret the linear map as first a rotation in the plane given by $\text{Eig}(f;1)^\perp$ and f is now just a rotation of $\alpha$ around the axis $\text{Eig}(f;1)$. This is something that we can all easily draw by hand, but is there a good way to implement it in a computer plotting system. My Desmos / Geogebra skills (especially since we're now not working anymore with regards to the standard basis) are not nearly good enough for these kinds of tasks and maybe even an animations of sorts would be quite insightful.
The same problem goes for task two: You can easily show that $U = \text{Eig}(f;1)^\perp$, so g just reflects f(v) at U, so $g\circ f$ is just a improper rotation. But how can I show this graphically without just letting my computer calculate some values?
